# Start firefox and close after few minutes with batch file

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd

i have a small script that starts waits 60 seconds,starts firefox and runs a imacros script
but the problem is i want to close firefox after 60 seconds and start it again through loop.But what this script does is .It waits for me to close firefox.Then starts 60 seconds timer and then loops the script.

What i want to do is .It should not wait for me to close firefox and directly force closes firefox after 60 seconds and runs in loop

```
  @Echo off
:loop
cls
taskkill /f /im Firefox.exe
cls
taskkill /f /im crashreporter.exe
cls
timeout /T 60
    start "" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=l4lyt.iim   
timeout /T 60
goto loop
```

What am i doing wrong?why does it waits for me to close firefox instead of directly going to next line.
i.e

> timeout /T 60

Comment: Because the `start ""` should be on the same physical line as the parameters.

Comment: thank you soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the `start` command on a separate line from `firefox.exe`, therefore it launched a `command prompt` window and then *called* `firefox.exe` instead of executing it.

Additionally you don't need to use `cls` to clear the screen, instead use `>nul 2>&1` to suppress output from the `taskkill` command(s)

**Updated script:**

```
@echo off
    start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=l4lyt.iim   
    timeout /T 60
    taskkill /f /t /im Firefox.exe /im crashreporter.exe >nul 2>&1
%0
```